# IpV6 No network access

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, ipv6, homegroup

I'm Currently using Windows 8 on my laptop, and windows 7 on my computer. They used to be connected by the homegroup, which was brilliant, but now they can't find eachother anymore.
I've tried to figure out why and the most common answer is that the IpV6 is not turned on (or something like this, im not a great with technology), i've followed instructions from other people who have had the same problem but what has worked for others is not working for me, i can't seem to get it to work!

Answer (score -1):

Is the windows 8 laptop specified to be in the homegroup? You can achieve this by going to Start -> right click on computer then select properties, in the Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings there should be a 'change settings' link on the right hand side. If you click that it will come up with system properties. from system properties click change and then specify the workgroup for it to connect too. Hope this helps [Workgroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/join-or-create-a-workgroup)

Comment: No but they need to be in a workgroup to be in a homegroup! Thanks for the -1 [Groups](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-a-workgroup-and-a-homegroup)

Comment: So why don't you answer the question instead of commenting on mine to belittle me?